# How to rephrase "will become easier"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that can shorten "will become easier"? For example in this context:

> Moving boulders will become easier as better wheelcarts become available.

Comment: It's idiomatically perfectly natural to use present tense throughout in your context, so you could lose *one* word straight away - *Moving boulders **becomes** easier as better wheelcarts become available.* I don't know that you'd find a suitable single-word replacement for the (intransitive) verb phrase ***to become easier*** though. We often use *transitive* verbs in such contexts (*As better wheelcarts become available this will **make it easier** to move boulders*, or similar).

Comment: You can shorten it if you rephrase it completely: *Better wheelcarts will aid boulder movement.* This, however, changes the meaning slightly. What's the purpose behind shortening the sentence?

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks for the suggestion! I did not like how a similar sentence sounded, and was looking for ways to make it more concise. Both suggestions so far work in my specific context. Other than that, I was curious if such a word exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better wheelcarts will facilitate moving boulders.

Moving boulders will be facilitated by better wheelcarts.

you can choose, both are shorter.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/facilitate